# Django unable to locate modules

Tags: python, django

I set up a Django project using pipenv and have the virtual environment running using pipenv shell.  I have been trying to add a few modules to my project including django-acl.  However, whenever I $ pipenv install django-acl and then attempt to migrate I get the following message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoacl'
```

At first I thought that django-acl just didn't work but it's done this same thing with every module that I've tried to add since.  How do I fix this so that I can add django-acl and other modules to my project?

Comment: Your pipenv probably doesn't correspond to your python executable. What OS are you on?

Comment: perhaps this might help https://medium.com/@piyushmaurya23/setting-up-django-using-pipenv-cf8ff9b2caa6

Comment: I'm on Catalina.

Comment: That article is actually the one I followed to set up my project.  I havn't used pipenv before so I followed that and am getting this error.